# Merge two files depending on multiple matching columns

Tags: awk, annotation

Im trying to join two files depending on multiple matching columns. I want to compare columns 1,2,4,5 from file 1 with columns 1,2,4,5 from file 2 and then merge matching lines in file 3 with column 3 of file 1 and all columns from files 2.
I've already tried several awk command. For example : **1)** `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1$2$4$5]=$3;next} $1$2$4$5 in a{print $0, a[$1$2$4$5]}' file2 file1 > file3`   **2)** `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1$2$4$5] = $3; next} $1$2$4$5 in a' file2 file1 >file3` 
but i'm getting empty output. Could anyone help me with this issue ? Thank you

An example of what my files look like

**File 1 :**

```
CHROM,POS,ID,REF,ALT
1,69270,rs201219564,A,G
1,69428,rs140739101,T,G
1,69496,rs150690004,G,A
1,69511,rs75062661,A,G
```

**File 2 :**

```
Chr,Start,End,Ref,Alt,SIFT_score,SIFT_converted_rankscore,SIFT_pred,Polyphen2_HDIV_score,Polyphen2_HDIV_rankscore,Polyphen2_HDIV_pred,Polyphen2_HVAR_score,Polyphen2_HVAR_rankscore,Polyphen2_HVAR_pred,PROVEAN_score,PROVEAN_converted_rankscore,PROVEAN_pred,CADD_raw,CADD_raw_rankscore,CADD_phred
1,69511,69511,A,C,0.031,0.450,D,0.002,0.090,B,0.001,0.040,B,-1.52,0.370,N,2.8350.402,21.5
1,69511,69511,A,G,0.652,0.048,T,0.0,0.026,B,0.0,0.013,B,1.54,0.007,N,-0.784,0.041,0.047
 1,69511,69511,A,T,1.0,0.010,T,0.0,0.026,B,0.0,0.013,B,2.06,0.004,N,-1.639,0.014,0.002
1,69496,69496,G,A,0.404,0.103,T,0.401,0.331,B,0.061,0.254,B,-1.39,0.344,N,0.9700.187,10.49
1,69496,69496,G,C,0.348,0.124,T,0.988,0.604,D,0.865,0.597,P,-2.54,0.550,D,2.6520.380,20.5
1,69496,69496,G,T,0.177,0.222,T,0.999,0.764,D,0.96,0.686,D,-2.69,0.574,D,1.4030.232,12.80
1,69428,69428,T,A,0.878,0.026,T,0.981,0.577,D,0.899,0.620,P,-0.16,0.095,N,0.0240.096,2.821
1,69428,69428,T,C,0.001,0.784,D,0.995,0.657,D,0.969,0.703,D,-5.34,0.846,D,4.5330.607,24.3
1,69428,69428,T,G,0.013,0.538,D,0.999,0.764,D,0.984,0.745,D,-5.05,0.827,D,4.1000.550,23.7
```

**Wanted Output :**

```
ID,Chr,Start,End,Ref,Alt,SIFT_score,SIFT_converted_rankscore,SIFT_pred,Polyphen2_HDIV_score,Polyphen2_HDIV_rankscore,Polyphen2_HDIV_pred,Polyphen2_HVAR_score,Polyphen2_HVAR_rankscore,Polyphen2_HVAR_pred,PROVEAN_score,PROVEAN_converted_rankscore,PROVEAN_pred,CADD_raw,CADD_raw_rankscore,CADD_phred
rs140739101,1,69428,69428,T,G,0.013,0.538,D,0.999,0.764,D,0.984,0.745,D,-5.05,0.827,D,4.1000.550,23.7
rs150690004,1,69496,69496,G,A,0.404,0.103,T,0.401,0.331,B,0.061,0.254,B,-1.39,0.344,N,0.9700.187,10.49
rs75062661,1,69511,69511,A,G,0.652,0.048,T,0.0,0.026,B,0.0,0.013,B,1.54,0.007,N,-0.784,0.041,0.047
```

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing you're missing is that your files are comma separated, but you use the default (whitespace) field separator.

What you seem to want is

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
  NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5] = $0; next} 
  {ind = $1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5} 
  ind in a {print $3, a[ind]}
' file2 file1 > file3
```

(separating the fields with `FS` i the associative array key string just guards against false matches; if you just concatenate fields you can't distinguish between `"abcdef"` and `"abc""def"`).

Ex.

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5] = $0; next} {ind = $1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5} ind in a {print $3, a[ind]}' file2 file1
rs140739101,1,69428,69428,T,G,0.013,0.538,D,0.999,0.764,D,0.984,0.745,D,-5.05,0.827,D,4.1000.550,23.7
rs150690004,1,69496,69496,G,A,0.404,0.103,T,0.401,0.331,B,0.061,0.254,B,-1.39,0.344,N,0.9700.187,10.49
rs75062661,1,69511,69511,A,G,0.652,0.048,T,0.0,0.026,B,0.0,0.013,B,1.54,0.007,N,-0.784,0.041,0.047
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i did try to specify the separator but i get the same result. I also tried to delete end lines and then sorted files. But it doesnt change anything. I still get empty output.

Comment: @RokhayaBA do your files have DOS-style (CRLF) line endings by any chance? if so, either convert them to Unix style (with `dos2unix` for example) or change the awk record separator accordingly e.g. `BEGIN{RS="\r\n"; OFS=FS}`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. I was trying to delete line endings for each files first  (tr 'r' 'n' < file1 > file1new) before applying awk command. But changing the awk record directly was definitely the solution.